# Growing view while scrolling down

Tags: swiftui

I want to grow the green rectangle according to how much the user scrolls down. And shrink it when scrolling up. I set the height of the view to the scrolling offset, but I am unable to scroll at all. I had similar code working a few weeks back and I've been trying to replicate it to no avail, so I'm out of ideas.

```swift
struct TestView: View {
    @State var scrollOffset = 0.0
    
    struct FloatAdditionPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
        static var defaultValue: CGFloat = .zero
        
        static func reduce(value: inout CGFloat, nextValue: () -> CGFloat) {
            // have tried "value = nextValue()" but get same behavior
            value += nextValue()
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                Rectangle()
                    .foregroundStyle(.green)
                    .frame(width: 200, height: max(scrollOffset, 0))
                
                Text("Offset: \(scrollOffset)")
            }
            .background {
                GeometryReader { proxy in
                    Color.clear
                        .preference(key: FloatAdditionPreferenceKey.self,
                                    value: proxy.frame(in: .global).minY)
                }
            }
            .onPreferenceChange(FloatAdditionPreferenceKey.self) { newValue in
                scrollOffset = newValue
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is good. This may be an iOS 17.0.1 simulator bug. I tried it on iOS 17.1.2 and 16.6 devices, as well as 16.0 sim and it works as expected.